# Can I install a custom handler for cases when bad_cast is thrown?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, error-handling, dynamic-cast

In case `dynamic_cast<SomeType&>` fails `bad_cast` exception is thrown. In my code there's a separate hierarchy of exceptions and `bad_cast` is not in that hierarchy so my code won't handle `bad_cast`. May I have some other exception thrown instead?

I mean I'd like to write a custom handler like this:

```
void OnBadCast()
{ 
    throw MyException( "Bad cast" );
}
```

and somehow register it in C++ runtime

```
RegisterMyBadCastHandler( &OnBadCast );
```

so that this handler is invoked instead of `bad_cast` being thrown.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can make your own dynamic cast that wraps dynamic cast and translates the exception

Comment: Don't catch it. If you want to try-and-cast, then use the pointer form of `dynamic_cast` and test for null after the cast. Then, use the reference form in the cases where the type is expected, and where `std::bad_cast` is an indication that there is a bug in your program. In this case, you want it to bubble up and *stop the program*.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Stopping the program immediately is not always an option. Sometimes it's better to log the exception and proceed to next item of stuff to do.

Comment: @sharptooth: this is rare enough to be handled locally. See my answer for an update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change this behaviour.

What you *could* do, is use your own caster, however:

```
template<class T, class E> T myCast(E expr)
{
    try
    {
        return dynamic_cast<T>(expr);
    }
    catch(std::bad_cast e)
    {
        // custom handler
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad casts usually indicate a bug in the program (like eg. out of range, or out of memory), and thus should not be caught at all (or perhaps at the top-level). If you want to branch upon the success of `dynamic_cast`, then test for null in the pointer form:

```
if (T* p = dynamic_cast<T*>(some_ptr))
{
    // Do something with p
}
```

If you want a special handler, the best you can do is thus the following:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T& polymorphic_cast(U& x)
{
    if (T* p = dynamic_cast<T*>(&x)) return *p;

    my_handler();
}
```

where `my_handler` is supposed to kill the program (and perhaps log the error). But here, you may prefer using the plain `dynamic_cast<T&>` form, let `std::bad_cast` bubble up and be logged at the top level. This also plays better with debuggers, which can be set up to stop at the point where the cast fails.

Cases like you describe in your comments are rare enough to warrant special consideration, eg.:

```
if (auto p = dynamic_cast<foo*>(q)) { do_something(); }
else { throw bail_me_out_of_here(); }
```

may be used to indicate some upstream strategist that it should try another method.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have exceptions in the same hierarchy to handle them. At least not in VC++. If you are just worried about handling different types of errors, do something like the below. If this answer does not suffice, the others are excellent considering the limitations you are working with, although take note of when bad_cast is thrown and when it is not. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071106101012AAggZAk

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

class my_exception {
public:
    explicit my_exception() {};
    const char* msg() const { return "my_exception"; }
};

int main()
{

    try {

        // comment either line.
        throw std::exception("std::exception");
        throw my_exception();

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e )
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (const my_exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.msg() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```